# How do I combine all tuples from a list to a single list? Also compare first line from the list with all others

Tags: python-3.x

This is my function, It has to raise an exception in case if there is wrong input or empty file. Still have to modify it to be only output string line like ("Wrong output") or ("No such file exist") without getting an error. Whatever the main problem is that I don't know how to finish my second function. Description for my next function is lower.

```
def create_time_list(filename):
    f = open(filename,"r")

    f.seek(0)
    fchar = f.read(1)
    if not fchar:
        raise Exception("EmptyFileError")

    f.seek(0)

    time_list = []

    for line in f:
        subtuple = tuple(line.split())
        for i in subtuple:
            if len(i) > 2 or len(i) < 1 :
                raise Exception("ImproperTimeError")
        if not subtuple[0].isdigit() or not subtuple[1].isdigit() or (int(subtuple[0]) > 12) or (int(subtuple[1]) > 59):
            raise Exception("ImproperTimeError")
        time_list.append(subtuple)
    return time_list
```

After I call the function:

```
TimeList = create_time_list("D:\\test.txt")
```

This is the output of my TimeList:

```
[('2', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('3', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('1', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]
```

I want to combine it in one single list with colon in between the numbers and space between number and meridiem, to get an output like this :

```
['2:12 PM' , '8:23 PM' , '4:03 AM' , '1:34 AM' , '3:48 PM' , '4:13 AM' ,'1:09 AM' , '3:12 PM' , '4:10 PM']
```

Also I do have a target variable that is taking first line from the List and must to compare it with all the lines to see how far in the future is the time, for example:
code for assigning target variable :

```
with open("D:\\test.txt", "r") as file:
target = file.readline()
for last_line in file:
    pass
```

output :

```
2 12 PM
```

I need to compare target with him self and all other lines from the list to get difference in time.
Some like :

```
(2, 13, 'PM')   (0, 1)  1 minute in the future
(4, 20, 'PM')   (2, 8)  2 hours and 8 minutes in the future
(2, 12, 'AM')   (12, 0) 12 hours in the future
(2, 11, 'PM')   (23, 59)    23 hours and 59 minutes in the future
(2, 12, 'PM')   (0, 0)  now
```

Any thoughts how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions as you asked.

A list comprehension would be a succinct way to convert the list of tuples to a list of strings.

```py
tuples = [('2', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('3', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('1', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]

strings = [ tuple_to_str(x) for x in tuples ]
```

Now your problem has been simplified to "how do I write `tuple_to_str()`?

I will help you a bit more by getting you started on writing `tuple_to_str()`:

```py
def tuple_to_str(tuple):
   # transform the tuple into a string 
   return string
```

Comment: still stuck unfortunately((, its my second week of python honestly